# Split multiple values in a row into multiple rows using pandas

Tags: pandas

My data is as follows:

```
d = [{'id':1, 'a':10, 'b':10}, {"id":2,"a":20, "b":20}]
```

The result I want is as follows:

```
res = [{'id': 1, 'prop': 'a', 'value': 10},
 {'id': 1, 'prop': 'b', 'value': 10},
 {'id': 2, 'prop': 'a', 'value': 20},
 {'id': 2, 'prop': 'b', 'value': 20}]
```

Since each row has two properties I want to split each row having the same id but different property and the corresponding value to that property

I am using iterrows as

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
l = []
for _, r in df.iterrows(): 
    for p in ['a','b']: 
        l.append({'id':r.id, 'prop':p, 'value':r[p]})
```

I get what I want but what I wish to know is whether there is any way to use purely pandas command to achieve my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) then use [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) with `orient=records`

convert string json to proper list format using `json.loads`

```
import json
d = [{'id':1, 'a':10, 'b':10}, {"id":2,"a":20, "b":20}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

res = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['id'],value_vars=['a','b'],var_name='prop')

json_res= json.loads(res.to_json(orient='records'))
```

```
[{"id":1,"prop":"a","value":10},{"id":2,"prop":"a","value":20},{"id":1,"prop":"b","value":10},{"id":2,"prop":"b","value":20}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `DataFrame` by constructor, then use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and last [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with parameter `r` for records:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#melt all columns without id
df1 = df.melt('id', var_name='prop')
#if necessary specify columns
#df1 = df.melt('id', var_name='prop', value_vars=['a','b'])

res = df1.to_dict('r')
print (res)
[{'id': 1, 'prop': 'a', 'value': 10}, {'id': 2, 'prop': 'a', 'value': 20}, 
 {'id': 1, 'prop': 'b', 'value': 10}, {'id': 2, 'prop': 'b', 'value': 20}]

print (type(res))
<class 'list'>
```